# анализ работы батареи android

Tags: java, android

Требуется анализировать работу батареи в реальном времени так, чтобы получить предположительные сведения о том, сколько осталось времени до того, как батарея сядет, а так же расход батареи в процентах в минуту. Подскажите, пожалуйста, инструменты, которые могут в этом помочь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для начала нужно узнать какое текущее состояние зарядки:

```
IntentFilter ifilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED);
Intent batteryStatus = context.registerReceiver(null, ifilter);
```

дальше вы можете узнать текущий статус батареи:

```
// Зарядились/заряжаемся?
int status = batteryStatus.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_STATUS, -1);
boolean isCharging = status == BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_CHARGING ||
                     status == BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_FULL;

// Как именно мы заряжаемся?
int chargePlug = battery.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_PLUGGED, -1);
boolean usbCharge = chargePlug == BATTERY_PLUGGED_USB;
boolean acCharge = chargePlug == BATTERY_PLUGGED_AC;
```

Следующий этап - отслеживание изменения состояния батареи. Для этого вам нужно в манифесте добавить ресивер для получения данных о батарее:

```
<receiver android:name=".PowerConnectionReceiver">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED"/>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED"/>
  </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

и дальше сам ресивер:

```
public class PowerConnectionReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        int status = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_STATUS, -1);
        boolean isCharging = status == BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_CHARGING ||
                            status == BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_FULL;

        int chargePlug = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_PLUGGED, -1);
        boolean usbCharge = chargePlug == BATTERY_PLUGGED_USB;
        boolean acCharge = chargePlug == BATTERY_PLUGGED_AC;
    }
}
```

Текущий заряд ( в процентах) можно определить так:

```
int level = battery.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, -1);
int scale = battery.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_SCALE, -1);

float batteryPct = level / (float)scale;
```

Дальше вы можете отследить существенные изменения (так написано в доках и мне кажется что это очень разряженное состояние у батареи):

```
<receiver android:name=".BatteryLevelReceiver">
<intent-filter>
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_BATTERY_LOW"/>
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_BATTERY_OKAY"/>
  </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Вот есть [либа](https://github.com/google/battery-historian) для получения статистики о использовании батареи. [Вот](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/battery-monitoring) доки по теме батареи и получения статуса. [Вот](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/battery-historian) доки по вопросу оптимизации работы батареи. Вам для прогнозирования времени работы батареи нужно будет брать логи `BatteryManager` и дальше высчитывать скорость разряда исходя из полученных данных, и дальше из этой скорости калькулировать приблизительное (тут ключевое слово приблизительное) время работы устройства от батареи. Но это время может меняться в зависимости от того как интенсивно вы используете устройство так как на разряд влияет куча факторов, [вот](https://www.androidcentral.com/new-google-services-uses-more-battery-old-and-google-needs-fix-battery-screen-already) статья по этому вопросу. И мой вам совет - найдите какую-то более-менее адекватную программу для сравнения времени работы, чтобы у вас не получились какие-то магические числа исходя из которых у пользователя будет 100к мАч батарея на устройстве :)